# Разбиение строк в формате с фиксированной шириной полей и необязательными значениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, python-2.x

Есть большой массив данных.

Пример строки из массива:

```
20046 2005  27.0  44.3   9.0  15.9   3.6   9.2   9.2  37.5  18.3  18.6  24.4  26.0
```

Где первые два значения - номер метеостанции и год, остальные - температуры воздуха, начиная с января. Значения разделяются пробелами, при этом количество пробелов варьируется от 1 до 3. Значения температур, которые не были зафиксированы метеостанцией заменяется пробелами, т.е. в массиве допускается строка вида:

```
20667 2014   5.5   2.4   7.9   8.1              42.7              10.1
```

Необходима регулярка, которая бы разбивала эту строку на массив вида:

```
['20667','2014','5.5','2.4','7.9','8.1','','','42.7','','','10.1','','']
```

Comment: А вы документацию по регуляркам читали? Ответ: пробельный символ разширеный  знаком плюс.

Comment: В указанных условиях (нефиксированная длина поля) однозначная интерпретация данных невозможна. Например, есть данные за январь, декабрь, и ещё одно приблизительно посерединке... вот как определить, июнь или июль?

Comment: А почему нельзя регуляркой заменить все пробелы на запятые и потом запарсить в массив?

Comment: И что вообще за язык программирования?

Comment: @Yuri потому что срока "моноширинная" в которой выпавшие елементы тоже пробелы, но можно использовать `{}`

Comment: Если вы видели ответ, то я его обновил, ознакомьтесь

Comment: можно поинтересоваться? вы хотите "парсить" `fixed width fields` файл?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По описанию ваших входных данных, похоже что это `fixed-width` файл.

В этом случае будет очень удобно воспользоваться [Pandas модулем](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['id', 'year'] + ['m{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 13)]
df = pd.read_fwf(r'D:\temp\.data\655212.txt', header=None, names=cols)
print(df)
```

Результат:

```
In [136]: df
Out[136]:
      id  year    m1    m2   m3    m4   m5   m6    m7    m8    m9   m10   m11   m12
0  20046  2005  27.0  44.3  9.0  15.9  3.6  9.2   9.2  37.5  18.3  18.6  24.4  26.0
1  20047  2005  26.5   NaN  7.5  17.3  NaN  NaN  10.2  39.9  19.7   NaN  20.4  20.0
```

Также можно воспользоваться [идеей от @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655212/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba/655379?noredirect=1#comment940160_655379) для того чтобы назвать столбцы по именам месяцев:

```
import calendar

cols = ['id', 'year'] + list(calendar.month_abbr)[1:]

df = pd.read_fwf(r'D:\temp\.data\655212.txt', header=None, names=cols)
```

Результат:

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
      id  year   Jan   Feb  Mar   Apr  May  Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
0  20046  2005  27.0  44.3  9.0  15.9  3.6  9.2   9.2  37.5  18.3  18.6  24.4  26.0
1  20047  2005  26.5   NaN  7.5  17.3  NaN  NaN  10.2  39.9  19.7   NaN  20.4  20.0
```

Исходный файл:

```
20046 2005  27.0  44.3   9.0  15.9   3.6   9.2   9.2  37.5  18.3  18.6  24.4  26.0
20047 2005  26.5         7.5  17.3              10.2  39.9  19.7        20.4  20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Предполагая, что под каждую температуру месяца отводится ровно 6 позиций (фиксированная ширина полей), можно распознать данные со стандартного ввода или из файлов, заданных в командной строчке, используя `fileinput` стандартный модуль:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

width = 6
for line in fileinput.input():
    station_id, year, s = line.split(None, 2)
    s = s.rstrip('\n').rjust(12 * width)  # pad with leading space
    temps = [s[i:i+width].strip() for i in range(0, len(s), width)]
    print(temps)
```

#### [Пример](http://ideone.com/1bwQtb)

```
$ python parse-fixed-width-temps.py input.txt
['27.0', '44.3', '9.0', '15.9', '3.6', '9.2',  '9.2', '37.5', '18.3', '18.6', '24.4', '26.0']
['5.5',   '2.4', '7.9',  '8.1',    '',    '', '42.7',      '',    '', '10.1',     '',     '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что каждая строка имеет фиксированную длину (82 символа), и под каждый месяц в строке отведено 5 символов (XX.XX), получаем, что разделителем должны быть два пробельных символа.

Значит, можно заменить лишние пробелы на отсутствующее значение + пробелы-разделители, и попробовать поделить строку следующим образом:

```
data = '20667 2014   5.5   2.4   7.9   8.1              42.7              10.1            '

print [val.strip() for val in data.replace('      ', '  n/d ').split('  ')]

>>> ['20667 2014', '5.5', '2.4', '7.9', '8.1', 'n/d', 'n/d', '42.7', 'n/d', 'n/d', '10.1', 'n/d', 'n/d']
```